# How to create an iterator that will yield lines of an HTTP response body in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, http, stream, request

The closest I've got is

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<dynamic>> GetResults(string id, int n) {
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Token " + token);
    Stream results = await client.GetStreamAsync(baseurl + id + "/results");

    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(results);
    while(!sr.EndOfStream) {
        string line = await sr.ReadLineAsync();
        yield return Json.Decode(line);
    }
}
```

But it says that it cannot be an iterator block because `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<dynamic>>` is not an iterator interface type.

However, I can't find a way to get a stream without an async method (I can only find GetStreamAsync, no definition for GetStream) and that forces me to have an async method, which forces me to return a Task.

Answer (score 0):

In order to stream a response, you'll have to write to the response stream manually. You can use a `PushStreamContent`, and pass in a delegate that writes a line to the output stream as soon as it's ready to be sent:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetResults(string id, int n) {
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Token " + token);
    Stream results = await client.GetStreamAsync(baseurl + id + "/results");

    response.Content = new PushStreamContent(
        async (outputStream, httpContent, transportContext) => {
            using(outputStream)
            {
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(results);
                while(!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string line = await sr.ReadLineAsync();
                    var decoded = Json.Decode(line);

                    //convert to byte array
                    byte[] buffer = //...

                    await outputStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                }
            }
    });
}
```

See [Asynchronous Streaming in ASP.NET WebApi](http://weblogs.asp.net/andresv/asynchronous-streaming-in-asp-net-webapi) for more details.

---

**Old Answer**

As the compiler says, you need to return either an `IEnumerable` or an `IEnumerator`.

If you returned a `Task<IEnumerable<T>>`, how would a client handle it? 
`foreach` calls `MoveNext()` on the enumerable - instead, it would have to call `await MoveNext`. `IEnumerable` and `Task<IEnumerable>` are not interchangeable.

You'll have to collect your results before returning an enumerable to the client.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<dynamic>> GetResults(string id, int n) {

    //...

    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(results);
    List<string> results = new List<string>();
    while(!sr.EndOfStream) {
        string line = await sr.ReadLineAsync();
        results.Add(line);
    }

    return results;
}
```

Comment: @JoãoPintoJerónimo What's the purpose of the iterator in this case? What's your requirement?

Comment: I need it to yield lines from the response body as soon as they are ready to be read. It's a trivial thing to do in python, I imagined it would be trivial in c# as well... or at least possible ?

Comment: @JoãoPintoJerónimo There *is* a workaround, but it wouldn't be of much help here. But isn't this an HTTP call? If you want to return lines as they are ready to be read, then you'd have to return multiple responses, one at a time, one for each line, which you can't do with HTTP. Unless this is not a response to an HTTP request at all, and I assumed too much.

Comment: This is an http GET request, I want to `yield` lines as they are ready to be read. Like [this](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#streaming-requests)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do it using the [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/456dfw4f(v=vs.110).aspx) class and following the example on that page:

```
public IEnumerable<dynamic> GetResults(string id, int n) {

    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(baseurl + id + "/results");
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Token " + token);
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(responseStream);
    while(!sr.EndOfStream) {
        string line = sr.ReadLine();
        yield return Json.Decode(line);
    }
}
```

WebResponse has a `GetResponseStream`, whereas `HttpClient` only had a `GetStreamAsync`. That allows me to not have to await and not have an async method.

Comment: This won't return the lines to the client as soon as they're ready. ASP.NET will still read the whole enumerable and send the response in one go. See my updated answer for how to send a streamed response to the client.